# Prestashop different views for different products

Tags: php, prestashop

How can I have separate views for different products? So for example, I want the default view for products, but for a certain product use a view which I custom create.

So I am thinking this way. I have ProductController which now is using the default product.tpl. But for some products I choose i want it to use another template file which shows the information differently. Also maybe this selection of products to be done from Admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy thing is to check the id of the product directly with smarty, and change html accordingly.

Another way, if you want to use a different template file, you can override ProductController and its initContent() method. The template is setted on its last line:

```
$this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'product.tpl');
```

So you can check the id/ids and use different templates accordingly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the solution that I have already figured out and used. I am overriding ProductCOntroller and overriding the template if it is my product. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create in your controller an associative array that containts your tpl's files and id of product to exclude , as key:

```
$excludedProducts = array(
'180'=>'template1.tpl',
'271'=>'template2.tpl',
'341'=>'template3.tpl',

)
```

and check if current product exists in keys of this array  using `array_key_exists()` , then redirect according to condition.